# How to compile and run a Node.js app on Heroku from a repository's subdirectory instead of the repository's root using npm scripts?

Tags: heroku

How can I compile and run a Node.js app on Heroku from a repository's subdirectory instead of the repository's root using npm scripts? There seem to be various other sort of fixes including git subtrees etc. but I'd like to do this with the tools I already have, i.e. npm and its `package.json`.

In the monorepo's root I have this kind of `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd packages/backend && npm install && tsc",
    "tsc": "npm run tsc",
    "start": "node packages/backend/build/index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

The scripts are intended switch to the correct subdirectory `packages/backend`, install its deps from its separate `package.json` and then build with `tsc`. After that Node.js should run the built app as defined in the `start` script.

This doesn't seem to work. Heroku build log contains the following line:
`sh: 1: tsc: not found`

How to make the scripts right?

I also tried without the middle `tsc` script in the above:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd packages/backend && npm install && tsc",
    "start": "node packages/backend/build/index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

Idea of the monorepo's structure:

```
monorepo
├── packages
│   ├── backend           # a TypeScript app that I try to run on Heroku
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── frontend          # a React client deployed elsewhere (Netlify)
└── package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't figure out how to run backend completely from a monorepo's subdirectory I decided to have its dependencies declared at the monorepo root and just have the source in a subdir. Frontend is deployed on a more adjustable platform, so that I managed to get working from a subdir just fine. This is a bit ugly in my opinion but I guess I must accept Heroku's limitations here since I can't figure out an easy way around.

Comment: I can't believe I'm going to do that same thing...